# Input Value type=text returns Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good afternoon all, Im working on one of the *frontendmentor.io* challenges, and Im having trouble getting my input to register the value in my javascript file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        var submit = $('#submit');
        submit.click(function(){
            var name = $('#name').val();
            console.log(name);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  font-family: "Space Grotesk", sans-serif;
}

/* Remove default margin */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
figure,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Remove list styles on ul, ol elements with a list role, which suggests default styling will be removed */
ul[role=list],
ol[role=list] {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Set core root defaults */
html:focus-within {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* A elements that don't have a class get default styles */
a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

/* Make images easier to work with */
img,
picture {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/* Remove all animations, transitions and smooth scroll for people that prefer not to see them */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  html:focus-within {
    scroll-behavior: auto;
  }
  *,
*::before,
*::after {
    animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
  }
}
main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sectionOne {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-image: url("../images/bg-main-desktop.png");
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.firstCard, .secondCard {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  height: 275px;
  width: 450px;
  z-index: 6;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.firstCard {
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-image: url("../images/bg-card-front.png");
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.secondCard {
  margin-left: 400px;
  background-image: url("../images/bg-card-back.png");
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cardLogo {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cardNo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.cardInfo {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 90%;
}

.name, .date, .cvc {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.cvc {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

.sectionTwo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  height: 325px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 275px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form > *:not(button) {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}

input {
  height: 45px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1.5px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

input[type=text]::placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.multiBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.multiBox input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inputX2 {
  width: 60px;
}

.inputX3 {
  width: 150px;
}

button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: hsl(278deg, 68%, 11%);
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sectionOne {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .sectionOne {
    z-index: 8;
  }
  .firstCard, .secondCard {
    height: 140px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .sectionTwo {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 6;
  }
  form {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .firstCard {
    margin: 100px 0 0 50px !important;
  }
  .secondCard {
    margin: -200px 0 0 100px !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .firstCard {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 35%;
  }
  .secondCard {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: 40%;
  }
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Interactive card details form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Grotesk:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

  <main>
      <div class="sectionOne">
        <div class="firstCard" src="images/bg-card-front.png" alt="cardFront">
        <!-- <img class="cardLogo" src="images/card-logo.svg" alt="cardLogo">
        <div class="cardNo">0000 0000 0000 0000</div>
        <div class="cardInfo">
          <div class="name">Jane Appleseed</div>
          <div class="date">00/00</div>
        </div> -->
      </div>
      <div class="secondCard" src="images/bg-card-back.png" alt="cardBack">
        <!-- <div class="cvc">XXX</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionTwo">
      <form action="#">
        <div>
          <label for="name" >Cardholder Name</label><br>
          <input id="wholeName" type="text" placeholder="Your Name Here"> 
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="card number" >Card Number</label><br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000"> 
        </div>

        <div class="multiBox">
          <div>
            <label for="card date">exp. date (mm/yy)</label><br>
            <input class="inputX2" type="text" placeholder="mm"> 
            <input class="inputX2" type="text" placeholder="YY">
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <label for="cvc" >cvc</label><br>
              <input class="inputX3" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 123"> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button id="submit" type="submit">Confirm</button>

      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
  
    <!-- Challenge done at "https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" Coded by Abbigail Merrill -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I type in anything and click submit, my function runs and the console.log runs, but I cant seem to properly return the input value, its always undefined. Any help here would be amazing![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Please read [ask] and the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428), where the answer is "No."

Comment: I have updated. Sorry. You could have said that a little nicer. It is obvious I am a new user. Please try to be more friendly.

Comment: I'm unclear on how the way it was stated was unfriendly; it merely asks you to read a couple of documents. The fact that I asked to to read them, instead of assuming you had, indicates I did indeed know you were a new user and was trying to help guide you. That said, feel free to flag any comments you find unfriendly appropriately.

Comment: I did. Thanks. 

I did not perceive any form of what you said as talking to me kindly in that comment. You pointed out my issue, thanks for that. But you could have phrased it more like "This question has been improperly formatted. Please refer to [link here]". Your response came off very sarcastic and unprofessional to me. I don't have anything further to say and was not trying to be rude. I just wanted you to understand my POV. Telling 'where the answer is"no" was very sarcastic and demeaning. I am able to read the info at the link. I just didn't understand, and this was my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty convoluted. From what I gather.

```
$(function() {
    var submit = $('#submit');
    submit.click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        console.log(name);
    });
});
```

If you are using jQuery you should wrap it in document ready. Also,

```
$('#name').val()
```

Returns the value of element once, it doesn't subscribe to it. So you should pull every time you need a fresh value.

Edit: In your HTML `#name` element doesn't exist.

```
<input id="wholeName" type="text" placeholder="Your Name Here">
```

You used `#wholeName`. So change one to the other or the way around.

Comment: Please don't answer questions whose code is only available on another site. Wait until the OP pulls their code here.

Comment: I've adjusted my weird complex function to follow the structure of yours and wrapped my code in a document.ready function as well, but Im still getting "undefined" as my console.log return

Comment: Heretic Monkey, thank you I didnt know I needed to do that, I will adjust now with my code

Comment: Thank you @vfioox for your kind help. I am reviewing now

Comment: Bless you @vfioox, this was an embarassing second error to make . Thank you so much for helping me out with such kind words!